# Laravel Logging Via Slack

Tags: php, laravel, logging, slack

My `config` logging file is:

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily', 'slack'],
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver' => 'daily',
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => 'debug',
        'days' => 7,
    ],

    'slack' => [
        'driver' => 'slack',
        'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
        'emoji' => ':information_source:',
        'level' => 'error',
    ],
```

Also I set my `env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL')` in the `.env` file. I don't set anythings else.

Everything works perfectly, but when errors occurred in my Laravel application, two of the same error message create in slack channel.

I am using Laravel 5.6.

Comment: Try using a custom **EventListener** and listen to `illuminate.log`. Then send logs manually to slack using `Monolog`

Comment: @ArashHatami thank you for commenting for this question my dear friend, but actually i don't want to done this action manually, because there are no problem for push the errors to slack. and when i logged via the `Log facade` the error message logged into slack once but for auto reporting errors via laravel doesn't work correctly.  the problem is duplicate pushing this error message in slack. i don't know what is going on here, way laravel two errors push the slack.. and i need to understand why laravel done this action twice.